# conditional Hide/show the new link action in symfony 1.4

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I want to show/hide the new link action of the admin generator list depending of some db condition.

For example:
A "Group" have many "Evaluation", a teacher may create new evaluations only if the Group status is not ended. I want to hide the "new" link of the symfony admin generator list  depending on that. How can I do it?, I tried editing the _list_actions file with no success until now.

thanks.
Yoan

Comment: Group status is this 0 or 1 ?Or it is date?Can you show how you change your  _list_td_actions.php file ?

Comment: Group status is boolean. I updated the question, changed the file to _list_actions.php

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make it in a few ways.

1. You can hide link to the new action, but this is not very good,because users can create new evaluations with direct link.
2. So I recommend you next way.

Go to **cache/backend/prod/modules/autoNamemodule/action/action.class.php**

Copy to **apps/backend/modules/Namemodule/action/action.class.php**

next

```
public function executeNew(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    $this->form = $this->configuration->getForm();
    $this->product = $this->form->getObject();
  }
```

Than you need to check status. I do not now yon DB table name, so for example

```
public function executeNew(sfWebRequest $request)
      {

 $id = $request->getParameter('id', false);
        if (ctype_digit($id)) {

           $group = Doctrine::getTable('Group')->findOneById($id);
           $group_status=$group->getStatus();

                if($group_status== 0){

                  $this->form = $this->configuration->getForm();
                  $this->product = $this->form->getObject();

                }
                 else {
               $this->getUser()->setFlash('notice', 'Group status ended!You can not create new evaluations ' );
               $this->redirect('@yourmodulenamerout');  
             }

      }
```

So if Group status ended you redirect user to the index of you backend module and show user why he can not create new evaluations). You can also hide link to the new actions. In the same way but you must make it in _list_actions file so it is not very good practice.